# How to conditionally run code in bubbled event if sender is original source? (UWP app)

Tags: windows, uwp, custom-controls

I have a templated control in my UWP app that responds to a PointerReleased event. This templated control is nested in other instances of the control. So CustomContentControl belongs to CustomContentControl, which belongs to CustomContentControl ... and so on. This event bubbles up and it is important for the control to bubble up but one line of code should only run on the control I clicked on.

I need my event handler to conditionally run a line of code *only* if it is the control that I clicked on. I thought I could compare the sender object to the original source.

The problem is that when I try to get `event.OriginalSource` (event being a `PointerRoutedEventArgs` object), it does not return the custom control but rather part of the template used to make that control. I tried a search like so to find the parent (hoping to find my CustomContentControl) like so ...

```
// test to see if template part belongs to a CustomContentControl
var test = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
var found = false; var tryAgain = 0;
while (!found && tryAgain < 3) { //try 3 times and then quit
    if (test.Parent as CustomContentControl == null) {
        test = (FrameworkElement)test.Parent; tryAgain++;
        Debug.WriteLine(test.Name);
    } else {
        found = true;
        // do something with CustomContentControl ...
    }
}
```

... but by the time the loop gets higher up the hierarchy, closer to CustomContentControl, `test` becomes null (I cannot find the specific control it belongs to)

I'm stuck. My question is: how do I run a line of code *only* if it is the control that I clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I attach an event to a templated part of the control, that will only bubble to items within that control. Attach that same event to the control itself and it will bubble up (unless it is a custom event, in which case at time of writing, will not bubble).

This way, I can write code for an event that will only affect the control itself and other code that will affect the control and bubble up to other controls.

Inside my `OnApplyTemplate()` within my templated control ...

```
var templatedPartOfControl 
    = GetTemplateChild("TemplatedControlName") as FrameworkElement;
templatedPartOfControl.PointerReleased += method_noBubbleUp;
this.PointerReleased                   += method_BubbleUp;
```